# Centroid of country shape

Tags: geometry, geographics

How can I use `RegionCentroid[]` to find  geometric centroid of the given country shape?

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black], 
Polygon[Entity["Country","Italy"]]}, GeoBackground -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ImageMesh[]` and it works perfectly..

```
shape = GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]]}, GeoBackground -> None, PlotRange -> All];

centre = Binarize[shape] // ImageMesh // RegionCentroid

{161.979, 241.223}

Show[Binarize[shape] // ImageMesh, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[centre]}]]
```

[image]

Also it works for Japan , (when centroid is outside of the country's borders)

[image]

Or

```
shape3d = GeoElevationData[Entity["Country", "Japan"], Automatic, "Region"];

centre = RegionCentroid[shape3d];

Show[shape3d, Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[centre]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the data directly, asking for the "Location" property

```
loc1 = 
 Entity["Country", "Italy"][EntityProperty["Country", "Position"]]
(* GeoPosition[{42.8333, 12.8333}] *)
```

Or you can use the `RegionCentroid` functionality on the `Polygon` - but you have to reverse the coordinates in the end

```
loc2 = 
 Entity["Country", "Italy"]["Polygon"] // DiscretizeGraphics // 
    RegionCentroid // Reverse // GeoPosition
(* GeoPosition[{42.7927, 12.0783}] *)
```

The two points aren't far from each other,

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black], 
  Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], Red, PointSize@Large, 
  Point@loc1, Blue, Point@loc2}, GeoBackground -> None, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The `"Position"` property of a `Country` entity appears to always have integer latitude & longitude (or a fractional part with a small denominator — 5/6 in the case of Italy.)  I suspect that it's just a "nice" point that someone at Wolfram picked once upon a time, and doesn't have any special geographical significance.

Comment: Also, if the country has an odd shape, the centroid can be quite a distance from the location of the country's `Position`;  it can even lie outside of the country's borders, which the `Position` never does (so far as I've found).  See Chile, Norway, Vietnam, and Japan for various example of these behaviors.

Comment: I don't think this is a trivial problem at all, especially at higher latitudes. It involves computation of centroid over a region on the chosen geoid; just assuming planar geometry for longitude and latitude is typically an acceptable approximation, but hardly a proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
CountryData["Italy", "CenterLocationLink"]
```

> ```
> "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=+42.8333,+12.8333&z=6&\"
> ```

```
"q" /. URLParse[
    First @ CountryData["Italy", "CenterLocationLink"]
]["Query"] // Interpreter["GeoCoordinates"]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{42.8333, 12.8333}]
> ```

Comment: Do you know where this data property is documented, and what exactly it is meant to provide? I am skeptical of its output for Croatia. [Other methods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/283553/1000) put it squarely outside the country, but this built-in provides an output which is rather far from that.

Comment: In addition to that, I don't understand what's the point of the `URLParse` handling, when one can get the same output more directly by using `CountryData["Italy", "CenterCoordinates"]`. (I appreciate this might not have been available in 2017? It would be surprising given that CenterLocationLink is fancier, but it's not implausible. But either way there's no point now.)