# How to get the centroid of a geographical region? (or: the center of mass of Croatia is in Bosnia and Herzegovina, but where exactly?)

Tags: computational-geometry, geography, geographics

How can I get Mathematica to calculate the centroid of an extended geographical region (say, a country) in a way which (i) fully respects the spherical nature of the Earth, and (ii) involves a minimal amount of user-side calculation, i.e., shifting as much of the computation as possible onto built-in functions?

I am particularly interested in doing this for Croatia, and what I have done so far:

```
Show[{
  CountryData["Croatia", {"Shape", "Mercator"}],
  Graphics[{
    Red, PointSize[0.005],
    Point[
     RegionCentroid[
      CountryData["Croatia", {"Shape", "Mercator"}][[1, 3]]]]
    }]
  }, ImageSize -> 800]
```

> [image]

(For the curious, this Mercator calculation seems to basically put the centroid on [the restaurant Breza](https://goo.gl/maps/KXxztgEjLbVm3LTp7), just across the Una river from the border.)

However, I'm not very keen on the use of the Mercator projection, so I would like something which removes all dependence on planar projections and puts things back to the sphere so there can be something like an unambiguous answer. (Obviously, this will put the centroid somewhere under the Earth's surface, and I have no problem with re-projecting back to the surface.)

How can this be done in a simple and idiomatically-Mathematica-y way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centroid of country shape](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139471/centroid-of-country-shape) Note that `Entity["Country", "Croatia"]["Polygon"]` returns a 3D polygon.

Comment: `RegionCentroid[CountryData["Croatia"]["Polygon"]]`

Comment: I have an uncertainty about whether the centroid calculated from the "surface" of Croatia is the same as the "center of mass" that you are asking for. I would think that the volume of a large mountain would "attract" the center of mass more than just its surface would. And do we need to account for varying densities throughout the ground? It also raises the question of where the "base" of Croatia is. Maybe we need to think of it sort of like a cone with apex at Earth's center of mass?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is superfluous--I offer it only to clarify my comments about the other answer. As Henrik already pointed out, we can get the apparently desired result easily thus:

```
RegionCentroid[CountryData["Croatia"]["Polygon"]]
```

`GeoPosition[{45.0732, 16.4233, -1452.97}]`

Without knowing about `RegionCentroid`, what would one do? The geodesy-related functions are still powerful enough to admit a fairly straightforward solution. One does not need to put much effort into translating between coordinate systems, 2D versus 3D representations, nor weighted averages.

```
With[
  {cells = MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[Entity["Country", "Croatia"]["Polygon"]], 2]},
  GeoPosition[GeoPositionXYZ[Mean[WeightedData[Mean @@@ cells, Area /@ cells]]]]]
```

`GeoPosition[{45.0732, 16.4233, -1452.97}]`

Comment: Thank you! Otherwise, our methods are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

**After Domen pointed out Henrik Schumacher's code in the latter's *comment* (which I had overlooked), *RegionCentroid[CountryData["Croatia"]["Polygon"]]* does, in fact, answer the questioner's question correctly.**

This is the pertinent part of *RegionCentroid*'s documention:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Live and learn.*

The questioner asked for the country's *center of gravity* **fully respect[*ing*] the spherical nature of the Earth.** This makes the problem a little harder than just the country's planar centroid.

```mma
country = (TriangulateMesh[Polygon[#1], 
    MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"] & ) /@ 
    CountryData["Croatia", "FullCoordinates"]; 
    
triangles = Flatten[(MeshPrimitives[#1, 2] & ) /@ country, 1]; 

xyz = Function[triangle, Triangle[(GeoPositionXYZ @* GeoPosition /@
    triangle[[1]])[[All, 1]]]]; 
    
weightsAndBalances = ({Area[#1], RegionCentroid[#1]} & ) /@
    xyz /@ triangles; 
    
weight = Total[weightsAndBalances[[All,1]]]

center = GeoPosition[GeoPositionXYZ[
    Total /@ Transpose[(#1[[1]]*#1[[2]] & ) /@
    weightsAndBalances]/weight]]
    
surface = GeoPosition[center[[1,1 ;; 2]]]

Column[(GeoGraphics[{Red, Point[surface]},
    GeoRange -> Quantity[3, "Kilometers"], 
    GeoZoomLevel -> 15, GeoBackground -> #1,
    ImageSize -> 600] & ) /@ {"Satellite", "StreetMap"}]
```

5.640867946082577*^10
GeoPosition[{45.03598624285783, 16.402204131119138,
-1483.9696823341578}]
GeoPosition[{45.03598624285783, 16.402204131119138}]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

1. This method does honor the general shape of the Earth. The necessary conversions are in the conversions from GeoPosition and GeoPositionXYZ and back again.
2. The method:
   a) get the polygon shapes of the country in latitude and longitude and finely triangulate the polygons.
   b) make a single list of the triangles
   c) xyz converts the triangles from latitude and longitude to XYZ coordinates,
   d) gets for each triangle its area and centroid location
   e) by the weights and balances method computes the *center of gravity* of the country. That turns out to be about 1,5 kilometers below the nominal earth surface.
   f) plot two maps

Because of Domen's confusion ("This method does not account for the curvature of Earth (which is what the OP want) because it is calculating everything from the 2D coordinates (given by CountryData["Croatia", "FullCoordinates"]).":

```mma
Graphics3D[Point[Flatten[
    Evaluate[Table[GeoPositionXYZ[GeoPosition[
         {latitude, longitude, 0}]], {latitude, 0, 90, 15}, 
       {longitude, 0, 90, 5}]] /. GeoPositionXYZ -> Identity, 
    1]], Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#1, Red, Bold, Large] & ) /@ 
    {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using Russia only because it is a large country in area:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From the backside, the line goes from the earth center through the geographic centeroid to edge of the graphic plotting area and the green ball on the line is that centeroid (about 400 kilometers below the surface):

[image: Mathematica graphics]